# Web scraping with selenium - 0 records returned

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am working with this code for a long time to solve my problem and cannot find a solution for this. Using Selenium, I have first logged on to the site and doing scraping. But its returning 0 values, which is not expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# Github credentials
username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
# initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\snyder\seaborn-data\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.finq.com/en/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id='login']")))
# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
driver.find_element_by_id("login_username").send_keys(username)
# find password input field and insert password as well
driver.find_element_by_id("login_password").send_keys(password)
# click login button
#driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='submit_login']").click()
# wait the ready state to be complete
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=10).until(
    lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'")
)
error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
# get the errors (if there are)
errors = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("flash-error")
# print the errors optionally
# for e in errors:
#     print(e.text)
# if we find that error message within errors, then login is failed
if any(error_message in e.text for e in errors):
    print("[!] Login failed")
else:
    print("[+] Login successful")

    
url = "https://live-cosmos.finq.com/trading-platform/#trading/Shares/Global/USA/All/FACEBOOK"
data  = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Instrument", "Sell", "Buy", "Change"])
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    Instrument = col[0].text
    Sell = col[1].text
    Buy = col[2].text
    Change = col[3].text
    df = df.append({"Instrument":Instrument,"Sell":Sell,"Buy":Buy,"Change":Change}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

After logged to the site, I am getting an another message which need to be closed. I gave the below condition for that too.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='popup-actions fn-close-popup btn autotests__popup-btn-close']").click()
```

But it says

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[id='popup-actions fn-close-popup btn autotests__popup-btn-close']"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

I see you switched to some iframe on login page to access some lements there, but after that to access elements out of that iframe you have to switch back to the default content.
**UPD**
To close the pop-up appearing after logging in you can use this command:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fn-close-popup.popup-actions"))).click()
```

Again, you have to switch to the default content after clicking the login button with

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the issue is after the login page, i am getting a pop up message. How to close it? Can you help me for that plese?

Comment: 1) You have to switch to the default content anyway 2) With the pleasure, but I can't register on that site. Even with VPN I see "We are sorry, but we currently cannot accept clients from your country." can you give me some credentials to login there?

Comment: Hello. Here are the credentials. Username - finqtest@gmail.com . Pass - Test1234 . After you logged in, it shows you a pop up window to add funds. I want to close it from selenium. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have "Login successful" then you need to replace:

```
data  = requests.get(url).text
```

with

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3) # import time
data = driver.page_source
```

Or you need to pass `cookies` from your Selenium `driver` to `requests` headers.

Comment: Its still getting 0 values. and here, after login page, i am getting another message to add funds. I need to close that message too. I have found the button name in the inspect element as 'icon-close-blue' but its getting Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[id='popup-actions fn-close-popup btn autotests__popup-btn-close']"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159). what would be the issue?

Comment: @SnyderFox Obviously it will not work if you can't load your `url`